# parse.com destroyAll not working

Tags: parse-platform

In the code following this description, I am trying to find and remove all these bad ListConfig objects that didn't have a group object set.  It is correctly finding them, however it does not remove them.  Is there something I am missing in the following code?

```
var Groups = [];

function queryForGroups(callback) {
    var Group = Parse.Object.extend("Group");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Group);
    query.limit(1000);

    query.find().then(function(result) {
        Groups = result;
        callback();
    });
};

function removeConfigs(){
    var Config = Parse.Object.extend("ListConfig");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Config);
        query.limit(10000);
    query.notContainedIn("group", Groups);
    query.find().then(function(configs){
        return Parse.Object.destroyAll(configs, {useMasterKey:true});
    });
}

function removeBadConfigs() {
    queryForGroups(function() {
        removeConfigs();
    });
};

removeBadConfigs();
```

Comment: in removeConfigs, the default limit of 100 is being used. Are you perhaps only deleting 100 at a time, or are no objects getting deleted?  It's better to use query.each() when you want to hit every object in a class. Alternatively, repeat the find recursively until there are 0 results. I also haven't used callbacks as you are, but is Groups even getting passed to removeConfigs()?

Comment: Also, the way asynchronous promises work is that the function is going to move on and if it reaches the end, return undefined.  So, removeBadConfigs returns undefined after setting up the query, even though the query is going to be running in the background. Use return statements before running your queries.

Comment: @JakeT. it isn't deleting anything.  Could you give me an example of what you mean about where to place the return statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I removed "useMasterKey: true" because 1) it isn't needed for objects not with elevated privileges and 2) I was not running it in Cloud Code.

Answer (score 0):

The code could be a little cleaner with respect to mixing promises, callbacks and an unnecessary global.  Beyond that, it looks like it should work as long as your data model supports it.  Specifically, your ListConfig object must have a "group" property, and it must have a Parse.Object value set for that property.  The most common error I've seen is something like this:

```js
var myGroup = // a parse object of type Group
myListConfig.set("group", myGroup.id);  // WRONG
myListConfig.set("group", myGroup);     // RIGHT
```

Assuming you've got that right, then it's mysterious why you're not seeing some deletes, but here's the code cleaned up with promises...

```js
function queryForGroups() {
    let query = new Parse.Query("Group")
    query.limit(1000);
    return query.find();
};

function removeConfigsWithGroups(groups){
    let query = new Parse.Query("Config");
    query.notContainedIn("group", groups);
    return query.find().then(function(configs){
        return Parse.Object.destroyAll(configs, {useMasterKey:true});
    });
}

function removeBadConfigs() {
    return queryForGroups(function(groups) {
        return removeConfigsWithGroups(groups);
    });
};

removeBadConfigs();
```

Comment: return queryForGroups(function needs to be return queryForGroups().then(function ... and Parse.Query("Config") needed to be Parse.Query("ListConfig").   Just like my code, this is finding the groups, and finding the ListConfigs (had to add a higher limit here too) (logging .length shows how many it's finding) but the destroyAll isn't removing anything.

Comment: The ones I am trying to keep have correct pointers to Group objects.  The ones I am trying to delete have bad pointers, hence the notContainedIn